# custom System class not compiling in command line

Tags: java, package, system

I have my own `System` class with a Test class in the same package which test methods declared in the System class. I also have created a System constructor which takes 3 parameters. When I created a constructor to test the methods in my IDE the program was working fine (I had use java.util.System where I need to use the System. methods) but IDE knew I was referring to my own class when I created the constructor. However, when I trying running my test class from command line it won't even compile:

```
error: constructor System in class System cannot be applied to given types;
        System sys = new System("String1", "String2", 20);
                           ^
  required: no arguments
  found:    String,String,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

My guess is that instead of my constructor, the `java.util.System` constructor (with no parameters) is being invoked which causes the whole program to crash. Does anyone know how to fix it and why is it only happening in command line and not in IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You mention `java.util.System`, but that's not where the platform's System lives; it lives in `java.lang`.

This is a problem. Java code acts as if `import java.lang.*;` is at the top of every file, even if you don't write it. The java language spec says so. So now you get into a fun dilemma:

Given a class named `System` in the same package, *and* you star-imported another package that also has a `System` class in it, which one is chosen if you use an unqualified type reference "`System`" someplace in the code?

The answer is presumably that whilst the spec is clear on this, few to no java coders care about the answer. They'd rather just.. not get into this bizarro situation. Thus, don't use star imports lightly, and don't name any classes the same as classes in the `java.lang` package.

If you must know, the order is as follows:

To resolve the type name `System` into which actual type it is referring to:

1. Check if there is a named (non-star) import for it: `import java.lang.System;`
2. Check if there is a class named `System` in this source file.
3. Check if there is a class named `System` in this package.
4. Check if there is a class named `System` in any star-imported package (and therefore, in `java.lang` as that is always star-imported.

Thus, given that it sounds like your `System` class is in the same package, that one 'wins'. However, if during a compilation run your non-test source files (your `System.java` file) is not on the classpath or sourcepath, then instead of the compiler straight up telling you this, instead you get the error you witness.

So, you have 2 problems:

1. you are not compiling the test classes on the command line correctly. Use a build system.
2. Don't name classes the same as classes in the lang package; whilst you can make code that works, and the ordering is well defined, it's confusing (hey, it confused you - that's anecdotal evidence right there!) and not idiomatic java. Other folks will have a very hard time reading your code, and you're likely to run into bugs in IDEs and such, because when you're doing weird unique things, odds go way up you run into scenarios nobody thought of and nobody ran into before.

Comment: thanks @rzwitserloot ! and yes, I meant java.lang.System not java.util. Unfortunately the task instructions are to create a class called System - I wouldn't do that to myself on purpose! I'm not sure in what other way I could compile it using command line that would fix this problem?